# Appending dataframe total to new dataframe

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, dataframe

I'm using pandas to calculate the sum of a column where "anystring" is in the filename and put add a Row "Totals_string" with the sum the requests for named "any string"

```
df = pd.read_sql("select count(*) as requests,\
filename,\
file_extension,\
date_trunc('day', log_time) as date\
from "+dbase+"\
where\
filename like '%anyStringA%'\
OR\
filename like '%anyStringB%'\
OR\
filename like '%anyStringC%'\
and\
file_extension not in ('gif')\
group by filename,file_extension,date_trunc('day', log_time)\
order by requests desc",conn)
```

This creates a df like this:

```
requests    filename    Extension   date
0   10  xxanyStringAxx  .jpg    2018-10-31
1   8   xxanyStringBxx  .jpg    2018-10-31
2   11  xxanyStringCxx  .jpg    2018-10-31
3   12  xxxanyStringAxx .jpg    2018-10-31
.
```

I would like to create a new DF with the totals of each condition for example the 
data frame would look like

```
Totals_anyStringA = 22
Totals_anyStringB = 8
Totals_anyStringC = 11
```

As a suggestion from @sacul I did this:

```
Totals_df = (df.groupby(df.url_info_filename.str.extract('anyName(.*)')\
                        .requests.sum()\
                        .add_prefix('Total_')\
                        .to_frame()))
```

My error was :

```
AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'requests'
```

*also I only don't know how to do a new row for each of the different names, as you can see I was just testing with anyStringA but it should have all the names of interest in there somehow.

Thanks

Comment: For your attribute error, just capitalize `Requests` (because your column name is `Requests` not `requests`)

Comment: @sacul fixed example.. bad paste but the error is still there when everything is in the same case also updated example

Comment: try `df.url_info_filename.str.extract('anyString(.*)xx').requests...`

Comment: @sacul I edited the question with ^ example same error. the xx's just represent any character in the filename the ABC is just there to differentiate different possibility of names but its not literally A,BorC, apologies for being unclear.

Comment: If it's always 1 character, use `str.extract('anyString(\w)')`, but without a solid rule of what you are trying to extract, I'm not sure what else to provide

Comment: @sacul the filename can be anything I just want to be able to define what anystring is to filter on. for example thereisacatinthetree.jpg if my filter is *cat* then I expect it to catch that filename. but it could be cat, dog,potato doesnt really matter. Does that help?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/183160/discussion-between-chowpay-and-sacul).

Answer (score 1):

IIUC, you want to extract the string following `Album` and preceding the underscore `_` from filename, then groupby that, get the sum, and put it into a new table. If that's the case, you can do something like this (I've added some arbitrary albums to illustrate):

```
>>> df
   Requests    filename Extension        date
0    914208  AlbumA_100      .jpg  2018-10-31
1     73795  AlbumA_132      .jpg  2018-10-31
2     39651  AlbumA_130      .jpg  2018-10-31
3        10  AlbumB_130      .jpg  2018-10-31
4        15  AlbumB_135      .jpg  2018-10-31
4        85  AlbumC_135      .jpg  2018-10-31
4        15   AlbumC_13      .jpg  2018-10-31

totals_df = (df.groupby(df.filename.str.extract('Album(.*)_'))
             .Requests.sum()
             .add_prefix('Total_')
             .to_frame())

>>> totals_df
          Requests
filename          
Total_A    1027654
Total_B         25
Total_C        100
```

Comment: I use "AlbumX" it can actually be anything for example if the filename contained cat ie pictureofcatintree.jpg I may want a count of all the filenames that contain "cat". So my totals maybe *cat = xxx , tree= xxx etc*. I think your answer is on the right track of what I'm looking for except for the "extract" part which im not familar with.

Comment: I updated my example, im just stuck on part of your code for totals_df